# Problems with wifi after update to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I've got a Samsung Notebook (Samsung Serie 3 350V5C S0C i7 8GB 75 ) with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and problems with my Wifi connection to a Fritz box 7490 and the newest  FRITZ!OS 6.23.

Very often after a reboot or after a wakeup from suspend I can't get a connection to my Fritz WLAN router. What I do then is to turn off and on Wifi on the laptop several times and eventually the connection succeeds. But it's very annoying, since sometimes it takes a few minutes. When the connection succeeded it's very stable - until the next reboot.

Connection from my smartphone to the Fritz box works without any problem.

The problem came up after the update to 14.04. Before this there were no problems at all!

An excerpt of `dmesg` output:

```
[64955.314097] wlan0: authenticate with 00:00:00:00:00:00
[64955.338513] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 1/3)
[64955.445221] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 2/3)
[64955.577744] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 3/3)
[64955.685278] wlan0: authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out
[64988.072502] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[64989.696368] wlan0: authenticate with 34:31:c4:46:bb:62
[64989.720897] wlan0: direct probe to 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (try 1/3)
[64989.923506] wlan0: direct probe to 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (try 2/3)
[64990.127398] wlan0: direct probe to 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (try 3/3)
[64990.331315] wlan0: authentication with 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 timed out
[65001.959985] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[65003.585262] wlan0: authenticate with 00:00:00:00:00:00
[65003.609425] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 1/3)
[65003.756378] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 2/3)
[65003.860721] wlan0: send auth to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (try 3/3)
[65003.969166] wlan0: authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out
[65108.607374] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[65111.370109] wlan0: authenticate with 34:31:c4:46:bb:62
[65111.387626] wlan0: send auth to 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (try 1/3)
[65111.394219] wlan0: authenticated
[65111.397135] wlan0: associate with 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (try 1/3)
[65111.418411] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 34:31:c4:46:bb:62 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[65111.418483] wlan0: associated
[65111.418525] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[65111.418691] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[65111.422751] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[65111.422757] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[65111.422760] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[65111.422764] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[65111.422767] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[65111.422770] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[65111.422774] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[65111.422800] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[65111.422803] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[65111.422808] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[65111.422812] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[65111.422815] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[65111.422819] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
[65111.422823] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
```

The Fritz box log says this (free translation from German):

```
01.02.15    20:40:57    WiFi device logged in (2,4 GHz). Speed: 72 Mbit/s. MAC-Address: 50:B7:C3:51:E4:A5.
01.02.15    20:35:41    WiFI device logged in (2,4 GHz). Speed: 54 Mbit/s. MAC-Address: 50:B7:C3:51:E4:A5.
01.02.15    20:35:41    WiFi login failed (2,4 GHz): access check failed. MAC-Address: 50:B7:C3:51:E4:A5.
```

It says that access check failed. But eventually it succeeds!

The laptop has got a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01).

Comment: Could you try booting with an older kernel and see if that works ? There's "Advanced Options for Ubuntu " menu in boot screen, where you can select a kernel. Now, how about using `sudo service network-manager restart`? does that help to recover connection ?

Answer (score 1):

Neither booting different older kernels nor restarting the network as supposed did help.

I've found a workaround, which persistently works: Setting the WLAN security on the Fritz box from WPA2 (CCMP) or WPA + WPA2 to WPA (TKIP). Can't explain why, but it works.

> **Note added by editor**: This is not an ideal solution as WPA2 should be used whenever possible. Check related links [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/WPA_vs_WPA2) and [here](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/4143). So, in anycase, you should prefer more secured solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some updates under 14.04 (I found out in updates log) suddenly the wifi was gone. I managed to get it back, not sure how :-) I am low skilled.

I rewrote `networks`, ran `ifup` `iwconfig` ,  restarted and I am online.